# How I can reuse steps in cucumber testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I almost have similar steps for two different scenario. Only one step is different. Is there any preferred way to reuse steps.

```
    @no-database-cleaner
    Feature: Managing users parent child relationships
    In order to use Login portal
    I want to create parent child relationships


  Scenario:  Creating a child user with new ar_id
    Given I am on the homepage

    When I attempt to sign in with following user account:
      | email address         | password |
      | abc@company1.com   | password |

    Then I should see "abc@company1.com" message on page
    When I follow "All Child Users"
    Then I should see "Add Sub Child"
    When I click "Add Sub Child"
    Then I should see "Child Sub User"
    And I fill in "Email" with "xyztest@gmail.com"
    And I select "Medium" from "filter_level"
    And I choose "abc_id_yes"
    When I press "Create Child User"
    Then I should see "Child User is successfully created."
    And appropriate records should get created for the child user for new abc_id


  Scenario:  Creating a child user with abc_id with value zero
    Given I am on the homepage

    When I attempt to sign in with following user account:
      | email address         | password |
      | recdns@company1.com   | password |

    Then I should see "recdns@company1.com" message on page
    When I follow "All Child Users"
    Then I should see "Add Sub Child"
    When I click "Add Sub Child"
    Then I should see "Child Sub User"
    And I fill in "Email" with "xyztest1@gmail.com"
    And I select "Medium" from "filter_level"
    And I choose "abc_id_no"
    When I press "Create Child User"
    Then I should see "Child User is successfully created."
    And appropriate records should get created for the child user for default abc_id
```

Only step is changing here is

> And I choose "abc_id_yes" and rest are same. How I can resue the steps in different scenario.

Here are the steps definition. Same issue here I am using same code in two different steps except one line.

```
Then(/^appropriate records should get created for the child user for new abc_id$/) do
  parent_user = User.find_by_email("abc@company1.com")
  user = User.find_by_email("xyztest@gmail.com")
  user.default_filter_level.should be_true
  user.abc_id.should be_true
  user.parent_id.should == parent_user.id
  filter = Filter.find_by_user_id(user.id)
  filter.user_id.should == user.id
  filter.abc_id.should be_true
  filter.account_id.should == user.account.id
end

Then(/^appropriate records should get created for the child user for default abc_id$/) do
  parent_user = User.find_by_email("recdns@company1.com")
  user = User.find_by_email("xyztest1@gmail.com")
  user.default_filter_level.should be_true
  user.abc_id.should == 0 ##this is different
  user.parent_id.should == parent_user.id
  filter = Filter.find_by_user_id(user.id)
  filter.user_id.should == user.id
  filter.abc_id.should == 0 ##this is different
  filter.account_id.should == user.account.id
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cucumber side : you should use a Scenario Outline

```
Scenario Outline: Creating a child user with new ar_id
  Given I am on the homepage
  ...
  Then I should see "Child User is successfully created."
  And appropriate records should get created for the child user for <my_id>

  Scenarios:
  | my_id |
  | default abc_id |
  [ new abc_id |
```

And then, for DRY, I would change your step_definition :

```
Then(/^appropriate records should get created for the child user for (default|new) abc_id$/) do |which_id|
  parent_user = User.find_by_email("recdns@company1.com")
  ...
  if (which_id == "new")
    user.abc_id.should be_true
  else # default
    user.abc_id.should == 0 ##this is different
  end
  ..
  if (which_id == "new")
    filter.abc_id.should be_true
  else # default
    filter.abc_id.should == 0 ##this is different
  end
  filter.account_id.should == user.account.id
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `background` to reuse all common code that appears in `scenarios` within the `feature`. For a quick example, you have

```
Then I should see "abc@company1.com" message on page
When I follow "All Child Users"
Then I should see "Add Sub Child"
When I click "Add Sub Child"
etc.......
```

in both scenarios. Now you can but these in a `background`

```
Feature: Managing users parent child relationships
  In order to use Login portal
  I want to create parent child relationships

  Background:
    Then I should see "abc@company1.com" message on page
    When I follow "All Child Users"
    Then I should see "Add Sub Child"
    When I click "Add Sub Child"
    etc ......

  Scenario: # first scenario
    # this is different

  Scenario: # second scenario
    # this is different
```

Now the `background` will be run once before every scenario.

Thats the easy way to DRY scenarios

Comment: Great. :) How I can do this user.abc_id.should == 0 ? I am geting error saying cant compare zero.

Comment: no problem. Just start another question for that and I'll try to help you out. More people will see it and you will get better help and it wont morph the current question.